# Memory leaks and other resources after a process dies

Tags: c, linux

Suppose a program has memory leaks.

1) When a process dies (normally or segmentation fault), are those leaked memory freed?

2) What about **other resources** a process holds?

Comment: yes as long as it is not shared by any other processes

Comment: @AdrianComish can you tell more details?

Comment: @AdrianCornish I want to know which part is not guaranteed in Linux. I thought it must have been guaranteed otherwise I want a comment by Mr. Torvalds

Comment: @mask8 Think of the bigger picture. Linus does not control the language standards or implementation - C and C++ do not guarantee it. Every implementation is free do do what they want. If an OS implementation does this great - but since you are coding to a language standard and not an OS'es you cannot rely on this. Think of if you were running it on AdrianOS 2.3

Comment: @mask8 Does not matter - show me the written requirement that Linux frees the memory.

Comment: @mask8 You are completely missing the point. There is NO REQUIREMENT FOR AN OS TO FREE MEMORY NOT FREE'D BY THE CODE. If it does - wonderful - say I clone the kernel and change that - what rules/requirements/standard am I breaking - because I want to run this on my new phone/PC/washing machine hardware. Never rely on something unless it is documented in stone. This is equivalent to saying you can use a pointer that was returned from a local function that was allocated on the stack there - yes - it may work MOST of the time.

Comment: Oh and by the way _ I can call my new code Linux legally

Comment: What about 'there is no requirement' do you not follow - it does not have to be free'ed. You cannot rely on and Open Source Project to follow those rules - so do not tell the OP that is must be so. Look at the other answer where it says - it will probably be so.

Comment: @AdrianCornish when the process gets reaped by the OS, the VM space, and the associated hardware pages, are reclaimed. You're arguing a vacuous point, rather vociferously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stack and heap memory is freed and file descriptors are closed on all modern system, I think.

On POSIX systems there are a number of resources that are not freed when a process exits, shared semaphores, message queues and memory segments. These are meant to be persistent between processes, so they simply can't. It is the responsibility of the application to free them.

It could do that e.g with `on_exit` handlers, but usually there is a simpler way. For memory segments you would typically use `shm_unlink` after all processes have opened such a segment. The segment then ceases to exist when the last process (and its file descriptor to the segment) is closed.

Answer (score 7):

With most modern operating systems (linux, windows from around NT 3.5), yes.

Comment: Other resources like opened sockets, file descriptors etc. are also released on behalf of the process by kernel. Otherwise you can cause memory leaks in kernel which has some book keeping data structures for each of the resources.

Answer (score 2):

1) Yes, the memory is freed.

2) Different process model?  I don't know what you mean by that, but once a program dies, all the memory that it `malloc`'d or `new`'d is then returned to the OS and will be reallocated to another program later.

3) Once a program exits, all allocated memory is returned to the OS, however until the process is `wait()`ed by another process, there is a small amount of data such as the exit status waiting around for someone to collect it.  On linux, I believe, a normal process from bash/init will be waited and cleaned up automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You can safely assume with modern linux systems that the memory will be freed... However... Its not a guaruntee, and certainly not best practice.